# Why am I having encoding problems when reading special characters in a QR code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read a JSON in a QR code. The problem is that when reading it, it must have some coding problem, and it introduces strange characters instead of special characters like accents, quotes or symbols. The charset in the HTML is already defined as UTF-8.

JSON of the QR code:

```
{"status":2,"ts":1601999,"t_next_req":"3600","id":"ES0099","fullname":"José Manuel Cabo Martínez"}
```

JSON I'm reading:

```
ç000026^¨status¨Ñ¨2¨,¨ts¨Ñ1601999,¨t?next?req¨Ñ¨3600¨,ïd¨ÑËS0099¨,¨fullname¨Ñ¨JosÃ© Manuel Cabo MartÃ­nez¨*
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var barcode="";
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    //Check that the QR code has been read
    if(code==13) {
        wait = true;
        console.log(barcode);
    } else {
        barcode = barcode + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that the encoding/decoding is not being performed using the same QR code standard.

Comment: UTF-8 is not the default character set in QR Codes

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516612/choosing-a-character-encoding-for-qr-codes/61035910#61035910