# QR code scanner return arabic text inside the input

Tags: reactjs, electron, qr-code, barcode-scanner, arabic

I have made an Electron desktop application. This application has an input field, that accepts a sequence of alphanumeric characters, a GUID, which will be used to search for a record in the database.
The application is multilanguage, English and Arabic.

The issue is that on Arabic Windows, the scanned QRCode, returns the GUID letters as Arabic, therefore the match of the GUID saved in the database fails:

```
ؤشؤب88ؤ-4لا44-4يؤ8-9977-802ي1ش825ؤلاب
```

instead of

```
osh88u-4l44-4j8-9977-802j1u825alab
```

To me, it seems an issue with the scanner configuration. Is there a way to fix it from the application?

Comment: This article may be helpful. [Choosing a character encoding for QR Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51516612/9014308)

Comment: @kunif thanks, but the article talks about how to generate the QRCode. In my case, the QRCode is generated using only English characters present in ASCII, a-z and 0-9. Then the scanner that read the QRCode "translates" in some way the alphabetic characters to Arabic letters

Comment: If you have a way to get the raw data or keystrokes before converting them to text, why not get them and parse them?